# An example for a mathematical object that has two indexes, and is not a tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, tensors

I understand how to check if something is a tensor (if it transforms like a tensor, it's a tensor).

I have this example of a rank 2 tensor: $$\tau_{ij}=r_if_j - r_jf_i$$
and I understand that it is a tensor because $$\sum_j\tau_{ij}e_j$$ is a vector (e is some vector).

What I'm trying to find is a mathematical "creature" with two indexes (similar to $\tau_{ij}$) that is not a tensor. (I'm just trying to get a better understanding of what is a tensor).

Comment: Could you clarify what definition of a tensor you are familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical example of an object that fails to behave like a tensor is the $\Gamma_{ij}^k$.  If you prefer to have only two indices just contract one of them and use $\Gamma_{ij}^k v^i$ where $v$ is a vector.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a manifold $M$ covered with local coordinate systems $(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ then the transition maps
$$\psi_{\beta\alpha}:=\phi_\beta\circ\phi_\alpha^{-1}$$
are identified by two indices, but have no tensorial structure.

Comment: Nice answer, but I suspect that this answer and the one using Christoffel symbols above are a bit too advanced for the asker.